# Jacobians in Python --TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable, TypeError: <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> is not a number

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-algebra

My script takes an input of a matrix of equations to return the evaluated Jacobian matrix, but produces an error

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def diff(f, x, y, H=0.01):
"""
Function returns the partial derivative of a function f(x, y) with respect to x
"""
H = sp.Symbol('H', real=True)
df = (f(x + H, y) - f(x, y)) / H
return df 

def jacobian(f, x0=1, y0=1):
"""
Function returns Jacobian of a given array of equations at a specified x and y
"""
f = sp.Matrix(f)
x, y = sp.symbols('x, y', real=True)
J = sp.Function('J')(x, y)
size = len(f)
var = sp.Matrix([x, y])
J = sp.Matrix(np.zeros(shape=(size, size)))
for i in range(size):
    J[i, 0] = diff(f[i], var[0], var[1])
    J[i, 1] = diff(f[i], var[1], var[0])
return J.subs([(x, x0), (y, y0)])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

<ipython-input-114-aa651e97d674> in diff(f, x, y, H)
  4     """
  5     H = sp.Symbol('H', real=True)
----> 6   df = (f(x + H, y)-f(x, y))/H
    return df

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

When I referred [Integrals in Python: Add object not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468985/integrals-in-python-add-object-not-callable) it mentioned that I should use evalf instead.
I changed line 6 to

```
df = (f.evalf(x + H, y) - f.evalf(x, y)) / H
```

However, I still get the following error. Would appreciate help in debugging this.

```
<ipython-input-117-ff184b261da3> in diff(f, x, y, H)
      4     """
      5     H = sp.Symbol('H', real=True)
----> 6     df = (f.evalf(x + H, y) - f.evalf(x, y)) / H
      7     return df

C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\evalf.py in evalf(self, n, subs, maxn, chop, strict, quad, verbose)
   1307         if not evalf_table:
   1308             _create_evalf_table()
-> 1309         prec = dps_to_prec(n)
   1310         options = {'maxprec': max(prec, int(maxn*LG10)), 'chop': chop,
   1311                'strict': strict, 'verbose': verbose}

C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\libmp\libmpf.py in dps_to_prec(n)
     65     """Return the number of bits required to represent n decimals
     66     accurately."""
---> 67     return max(1, int(round((int(n)+1)*3.3219280948873626)))
     68 
     69 def repr_dps(n):

C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in __int__(self)
    192         # (regardless of how much extra work we do to calculate extra decimal
    193         # places) we need to test whether we are off by one.
--> 194         r = self.round(2)
    195         if not r.is_Number:
    196             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to int")

C:\Users\pearl\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in round(self, p)
   3040         x = self
   3041         if not x.is_number:
-> 3042             raise TypeError('%s is not a number' % type(x))
   3043         if x in (S.NaN, S.Infinity, S.NegativeInfinity, S.ComplexInfinity):
   3044             return x

TypeError: <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> is not a number
```

Thanks in advance!